# How to deal with commands of conflicting names listed in `brew doctor`?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

So after `brew doctor`I`ll get the following without any recommendation:

```
Warning: You have external commands with conflicting names.

Found command `brew-cask` in following places:
/usr/local/bin/brew-cask
/usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/cmd/brew-cask.rb
```

Is there a way to settle that conflict?

Comment: Since cask runs on top of brew - did you run the recommended cleanup tools? It's probably not going to solve things, but it might help isolate the issue to brew or cask: `brew update ; brew cleanup ; brew cask cleanup` - Also - could you list one cask you use so we can try replicating your setup?

Comment: For the first time I'll get the following when running clean up tools: `Warning: Skipping czmq: most recent version 3.0.2_3 not installed` `Warning: Skipping git: most recent version 2.6.4 not installed` `Warning: Skipping libsodium: most recent version 1.0.7 not installed` `Warning: Skipping node: most recent version 5.2.0 not installed`

Comment: I got the node warning - so I just `brew rm` those packages and will let them install next time I need them. I think a cleanup / migration step was added recently, but can't speak for certain on that yet without more digging. For now, I'm happy to have a clean cleanup run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use casks much, but on my test machine I just tapped the cask infrastructure to see what it installs today. I have the `brew-cask.rb` file and not the one in `/usr/local/bin`

If you have a backup system, back up and then delete `/usr/local/bin/brew-cask` and rerun `brew doctor`. You could also rename the file if you don't want to hassle with backups.

```
mv /usr/local/bin/brew-cask /usr/local/bin/ZZdeleteZZbrew-cask
brew doctor
```

That way a program or script calling the tool won't see the file (or sym link) in /usr/local/bin. You could then test things a bit and clean up the file in question. It also is easier to fix if my hunch that the one in `bin` is needed somewhere and the tool is wrong to complain about both.

Additionally, there looks like a change was made somewhat recently to cask/brew integration:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770168/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-cask

My uninstall steps were different than the ones linked above since I installed cask today and not from before. My results might not match yours in that case :(

Comment: I'll moved it and `Your system is ready to brew`

Comment: But the upper `Warnings` after clean up remains

Comment: @HiThere Yeah - I'm not always so hot to fix a brew doctor warning until I have an actual downstream error. Yes - they often can cause issues, but brew itself is so large - not everyone builds from source and not everyone uses casks at all. Some people only come for the casks. Please ping me if you have an error with a specific package install. I'm trying to learn more how the brews work, so I'm up for real problems to help troubleshoot and possibly solve.

Answer (score 20):

Important December update (from https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask):

Homebrew-Cask will now be kept up to date together with Homebrew.

If you haven’t yet, to switch to the new system, run:

```
brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew update
```

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks! Nice of you to post that command so that I didn't have to fish it out.

Answer (score 5):

You could also remove the cask additions and see if the clean up script removes the remnants:

```
brew uninstall --force brew-cask
```

At that point, you can re-run the [installation according to the current instructions](http://caskroom.io):

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

Just the uninstall alone solved your issue for me when I ran across it.

Comment: That seems like a better solution if it works :-)

Comment: May I ask what that command is doing?

Comment: I had two versions installed. This removed the offending one. See 
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md
for details.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact warning today.
For me, simple `brew update && brew upgrade && brew doctor` worked.

Got finally, the satisfying `Your system is ready to brew` log.